# XML not getting parsed properly on second attempt

Tags: javascript, android, xml-parsing, titanium, appcelerator

I am developing an app in Appcelerator Titanium. The problem which I am facing is that when I am parsing a particular XML for the first time on a button click, its working fine, but if I re-click the button, the XML should be parsed again, which is not happening. In the log I can see the updated values in the re-formed XML but when I am trying to parse it, the variables used in the parser are retaining their values. They are not getting updated. What is to be done to update the variable values of the Parser?

Parsing code:

```
if(xml.getElementsByTagName("d:user_id").length>0)
{
         Ti.App.information.user_id = xml.getElementsByTagName("d:user_id").item(0).text;
         Ti.App.information.organization_id=xml.getElementsByTagName("d:organization_id").item(0).text;
         Ti.App.information.uname=xml.getElementsByTagName("d:name").item(0).text;
         Ti.App.information.Lpassword=xml.getElementsByTagName("d:password").item(0).text;
         Ti.App.information.Lemail_id=xml.getElementsByTagName("d:email_id").item(0).text;
         Ti.App.information.is_valid=xml.getElementsByTagName("d:is_valid").item(0).text;
}
```

This is the function where I am using the **Ti.App.information.is_valid** variable:

```
function checkCredential()
{
    if(Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest(txtPasswordLogin.value)==Ti.App.information.Lpassword && txtEmailLogin.value == Ti.App.information.Lemail_id)
    {
        activityIndicator.hide();
        //alert("welcome");
        //Login.close();
        if(Ti.App.information.is_valid == 'true')
        {
            //Ti.API.info("..........Login Success........Getting Approved Forms..........");
            Ti.App.information.is_valid='';
             //alert(Ti.App.is_valid);

            // Titanium.include('Login.js');
             // Login.open();
             Ti.App.information.is_valid = '';
            Titanium.include('Home.js');
            Home.open();

        }
        else
        {
            // var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertdialogScreen({title:'Access Denied!'});
            Ti.App.information.is_valid='';
             //alert(Ti.App.is_valid);
            myAlert.title = 'Access Denied!';
            myAlert.setMessage('You are not authorized. Please contact Administrator.');
            myAlert.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                // Titanium.include('Login.js');
            // Login.open();
              Login.close();
      });



        myAlert.show();     
    }       
}
else
{ 
    Ti.App.information.is_valid='';
     //alert(Ti.App.is_valid);
    activityIndicator.hide();
    myAlert.title = 'Invalid Login!';
    myAlert.setMessage('The email address or password you entered is incorrect.');

    myAlert.show();
    // Titanium.include('Login.js');
    // Login.open();
    // alert("Please enter a correct password.");   
}

}
```

The variables are declared in **app.js** file:

```
Ti.App.information={base_url:'',uid:'',password:'',EmailId:'',pass:'',user_id:'',organization_id:'',uname:'',Lpassword:'',Lemail_id:'',is_valid:''};
Ti.App.authentication=false;
Ti.App.formid;
Ti.App.guid;
Ti.App.mydata={_guid:'',status:true,networkStatus:true};
Ti.App.formurl={burl:''};
Ti.App.glocation={longitude:'',latitude:'',gloc:''};
Ti.App.gloc;
```

This is a sample XML file to be parsed:

```
<feed xml:base="http://webdevhost.servehttp.com/iPhoneDataEntryService/iPhoneDataEntryDataService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <title type="text">users</title>
   <id>http://webdevhost.servehttp.com/iPhoneDataEntryService/iPhoneDataEntryDataService.svc/users</id>
   <updated>2012-10-26T04:05:48Z</updated>
   <link rel="self" title="users" href="users" />
   <entry>
     <id>http://webdevhost.servehttp.com/iPhoneDataEntryService/iPhoneDataEntryDataService.svc/users(34L)</id>
     <title type="text"></title>
     <updated>2012-10-26T04:05:48Z</updated>
     <author>
       <name />
     </author>
     <link rel="edit" title="user" href="users(34L)" />
     <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/user_type" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="user_type" href="users(34L)/user_type" />
     <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/organization" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="organization" href="users(34L)/organization" />
     <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/form_data" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="form_data" href="users(34L)/form_data" />
     <category term="iPhoneDataEntryModel.user" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
     <content type="application/xml">
       <m:properties>
         <d:user_id m:type="Edm.Int64">34</d:user_id>
         <d:organization_id m:type="Edm.Int64">1</d:organization_id>
         <d:name>test</d:name>
         <d:password>16690502e26791e97c6c4743d2d4cb9a</d:password>
         <d:email_id>ad@ad.com</d:email_id>
         <d:user_type_id m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:user_type_id>
         <d:is_valid m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:is_valid>
         <d:registration_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-10-18T10:33:13</d:registration_date>
       </m:properties>
     </content>
   </entry>
 </feed>
```

The **d:is_valid** is the tag which I have to parse at intervals, on click of a button.

The problem is that this variable is retaining its value even after re-calling the parser.

Comment: What version of Titanium SDK are you running?  I don't see an 'information' namespace in the SDK.  Are you attempting to set Ti.App.Properties?  Did you create your application specific variables inside the Ti.App namespace?

Comment: I am running Titanium SDK version 2.1.3. The variables are declared in app.js file.

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML file? I'll give it a try in a test project. I am not seeing any reason it should be retaining the values in the `information` object. Have you tried setting the `information` object to null and then setting the values?

Comment: @Ronnie I had posted it above, you can go through it!

Comment: is there ever more than one `<entry>` tag in this xml file or is this what a complete one would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Alright to change the object values, do it this way. I removed some of the objects that weren't being used so keep that in mind if you want to add them back in. I'd copy this code into a new project to just test it out and play around with it.

```
Ti.App.information = {
    user_id:'existing username val',
    organization_id:'existing org val',
    uname:'existing uname val',
    Lpassword:'existing Lpassword val',
    Lemail_id:'existing Lemail_id val',
    is_valid:'existing is_valid val'
};

function parseXML(xml)
{
    if (xml.getElementsByTagName("d:user_id").length > 0)
    {
        for (key in Ti.App.information)
        {
            //outputs the key => value pairs for some existing data
            Ti.API.info(key + ': ' + Ti.App.information[key]); 
        }
        Ti.API.warn('------------------------');
        Ti.App.information = {
            user_id:            xml.getElementsByTagName("d:user_id").item(0).text,
            organization_id:    xml.getElementsByTagName("d:organization_id").item(0).text,
            uname:              xml.getElementsByTagName("d:name").item(0).text,
            Lpassword:          xml.getElementsByTagName("d:password").item(0).text,
            Lemail_id:          xml.getElementsByTagName("d:email_id").item(0).text,
            is_valid:           xml.getElementsByTagName("d:is_valid").item(0).text
        }

        for (key in Ti.App.information)
        {
            //outputs the key => value pairs for the new data you set above
            Ti.API.info(key + ': ' + Ti.App.information[key]); 
        }
    }
}

function loadXML()
{
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(event)
        {
            Ti.API.info('loaded');
            parseXML(this.responseXML);
        },
        onerror: function(event)
        {
            alert('Error. Code: ' + this.status);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
    xhr.open('GET','http://ronnieswietek.com/feed.xml');
    xhr.send();
}
loadXML();
```

Comment: I have also posted the full source code in the question itself. Here is the link again: http://justpaste.it/1gwc